# MacBook Pro not detecting external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I have 2 MacBook Pros. A private (late-2013) and a work (mid-2012). My private MacBook Pro can detect the external monitors instantly without any issues. My work MacBook Pro can only detect one of the monitors.

The monitors are exactly the same (Fujitsu Thor) and I use a mini-DP -> DP cable.

I've tried resetting PRAM and SMC.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there seems to be something wrong with the cable.

I tried using the cable that I use to the monitor that was being detected and it works now... Is this a faulty cable or is the cable simply just not compatible or something?